# How to debug and fix binding in a nested wpf control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

The data binding is partly working in a UI with an ItemsControl showing a collection of Expanders, each with a DataGrid with two columns. The ItemsControl can get data from ItemsSource in code-behind, but not from a Binding. The Expander Headers show the data correctly using Binding, and the DataGrid shows the correct number of rows, but the DataGrid cells are empty.

This is the XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="TheItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding TheItemsSource}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander>
                <Expander.Header>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Key}" />
                </Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" 
                              ColumnWidth="*" 
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn 
                                Header="Label" 
                                Binding="{Binding Key.Value.Label}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn 
                                Header="Value" 
                                Binding="{Binding Value.DisplayValue}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is the code-behind with the data model built in. I know, the Data Model should be a separate file, but I tried to make it as easy as possible for the XAML to "find" the data.

```
public class ObjectProperty
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Content for the left column of the DataGrid
    /// </summary>
    public string Label = "";

    /// <summary>
    /// Content for the right column of the DataGrid
    /// </summary>
    public string DisplayValue = "";
}//end class

/// <summary>
/// UserControl to test tabbing in a complex UI.
/// Test data is a List of KeyValuePairs, where the Key is a kind of objects (Pipe, Line, ...)
/// and Value is List of ObjectProperties, each with a Label string and a DisplayValue.
/// </summary>
public partial class test_itemcontrol_expander_datagrid : UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return the list of items for the datagrid
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ObjectId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<ObjectProperty> GetRows(string ObjectId)
    {// Set up the collection properties used to bind the ItemsSource 
        // properties to display the list of items in the dropdown lists.
        string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff");
        var L = new List<ObjectProperty>();
        switch (ObjectId.ToLower())
        {
            case "pipe":
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Length", DisplayValue = "26.3 m" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Material", DisplayValue = "PVC" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Substance", DisplayValue = "Tar" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Address", DisplayValue = "Mainstreet" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "ObjectId", DisplayValue = ObjectId });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Length", DisplayValue = ObjectId.Length.ToString() });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Time", DisplayValue = now });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Width", DisplayValue = "0.15 m" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Weight", DisplayValue = "16.2 kg" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Orientation", DisplayValue = "Northwest" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Flexible", DisplayValue = "Yes" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Status", DisplayValue = "Half" });
                break;

            case "line":
            default:
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Length", DisplayValue = "1.23 m" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Material", DisplayValue = "PVC" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Substance", DisplayValue = "Tar" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Address", DisplayValue = "Backstreet" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "ObjectId", DisplayValue = ObjectId });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Length", DisplayValue = ObjectId.Length.ToString() });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Time", DisplayValue = now });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Width", DisplayValue = "0.15 m" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Weight", DisplayValue = "16.2 kg" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Orientation", DisplayValue = "Northwest" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Flexible", DisplayValue = "Yes" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Status", DisplayValue = "Half" });
                break;
        };
        return L;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the list of items for the datagrid as a Key Values Pair
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ObjectId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public KeyValuePair<string, List<ObjectProperty>> GetRows_KVP(string ObjectId)
    {
        var items = GetRows(ObjectId);
        var itemsKvp = new KeyValuePair<string, List<ObjectProperty>>(ObjectId, items);
        return itemsKvp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The entire dataset for display in the UserControl
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, List<ObjectProperty>>> TheItemsSource()
    {
        var itemsSource = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<ObjectProperty>>>();
        itemsSource.Add(GetRows_KVP("Pipe"));
        itemsSource.Add(GetRows_KVP("Line"));
        return itemsSource;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class initializer
    /// </summary>
    public test_itemcontrol_expander_datagrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //TheItemsControl.DataContext = this;            
        TheItemsControl.ItemsSource = TheItemsSource();
    }
}//end class
```

If I remove the ItemsSource attribute from the ItemsControl in the XAML, the Expander headers still get the data.

If, instead, I change the code-behind initializer to enable the DataContext assignment and comment out the ItemsSource assignment, the Expander Header gets no data.

My best guess for the Binding in the DataGrid columns was:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Label}"
```

but I tried several variations like:

```
Binding="{Binding Label}"
Binding="{Binding Key.Value.Label}"
Binding="{Binding Value.DisplayValue}"
```

I also tried Live Visual Tree, which gives a nice view on the nesting of the various controls, but I wonder if and how you can see the data flowing through the Binding. I do see two small dots indicating that this binding is wrong, but no such indication on the Binding in the DataGrid Columns:

[image: screenshot of failed Binding]

So I am wondering how a mortal can debug such Binding problems?

Comment: TheItemsSource is a method. In WPF you can't bind to methods. Only to public properties. Also the collection you assign to the ItemsSource should be a INotifyCollectionCHanged collection (e.g. the ObservableCollection). Especially in your scenario where you don't reuse the collection instance but always create new instances. The binding engine will automatically create a collection view of the collection set to the ItemsSource.

Comment: If this collection does not implement INotifyCollectionChanged it will be very difficult for the framework to manage the lifetime of the collection view and the underlying collection. Both are kept alive *significantly* longer than expected. If the collection is big, they consume a lot of memory. If you create that many instances you waste a lot of memory. For this reason, you usually use and reuse the same ObservableCollection collection instance by using Clear() and Add() (replace items).

Comment: *"Data Model should be a separate file, but I tried to make it as easy as possible for the XAML to "find" the data."* - Additionally, it doesn't matter where you define a class in terms of *instance* lookup. Only the compiler cares about where to find a class. The program only cares about instances of classes. It matters where an instance is created and where it is exposed to the public. In other words, having the data model class defined in a file on a different drive or machine doesn't make any difference.

Comment: The first step to debug a databinding is to understand how they work or how they are properly used: [Microsoft learn: Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0). For example, here you can learn that you can't bind to methods and what kind of members/objects valid binding sources are.

Comment: Next go to the "Debug" menu and open the settings. Go to the "Output WIndow" submenu. Here you can configure the "WPF trace settings". There is a setting named "Data Binding". Set the trace level to e.g. "Warning". Now when in debug mode you will receive binding errors and warnings (or information) based on the previously selected trace level. The error message tells you exactly what binding source the binding "sees" so that you know how to modify it.

Comment: @BionicCode sure, i know about ObservableCollection, but this is a small test project for fixing a tabbing problem. However, I need some data in the controls. Also this allows me to learn wpf from the bottom up. I will look at the debug output as per your info. Thanks so far!

Comment: Then never mind. I was just telling you about the issues I found with your code after reviewing it. Those issues can result in bugs you may have a very difficult time finding and fixing or serious performance degradations.

Comment: @BionicCode I implemented your points and the bindings work ok now. Apparently, INotifyPropertyChanged is not just a fancy kind of List, but is really needed even in the simplest UI. I also made the method to bind into a property, it did not make a difference, but I understand now that not adhering to the Microsoft way, you can expect all kinds of odd problems with wpf. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your original problem is to replace the binding to the `TheItemsSource` method with a binding to a property (in your case the property should be a dependency property).

Also never set the DataContext from inside a control. This will break external data bindings that you or the user of your control defines. Use `Binding.ElementName` or `Binding.RelativeSource` to bind internal elements to properties of the parent control.

Just as a note: you have a very strange and uncommon naming convention for your classes. The common convention uses PascalCase names for types. Like all the WPF and .NET classes do. It's not "items_control" but "ItemsControl".

You should also avoid binding `Label.Content` property to a `string`. In general, don't use the `Label` to display text. use the `TextBlock` which is highly optimized for displaying small text values.

Also consider replacing the `ItemsControl` with a `ListBox` which also performs significantly better (it's an extended `ItemsControl`).

**test_itemcontrol_expander_datagrid.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl x:Name="Root">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=TheItems}" />
</UserControl>
```

**test_itemcontrol_expander_datagrid.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class test_itemcontrol_expander_datagrid : UserControl
{
  public IList TheItems
  {
    get => (IList)GetValue(TheItemsProperty);
    set => SetValue(TheItemsProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty TheItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "TheItems", 
    typeof(IList), 
    typeof(test_itemcontrol_expander_datagrid), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public test_itemcontrol_expander_datagrid()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.TheItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();

    // Initialize the control from the Loaded event 
    // to avoid time consuming work in the constructor.
    // Important: you can use async/await outside the constructor!
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

 // Declare as async void if you need to use asynchronous initiaization
  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => TheItemsSource();

  private void TheItemsSource()
  {
    // Reuse the existing collection instance to improve 
    // rendering performance and memory management
    this.TheItems.Clear();

    this.TheItems.Add(GetRows_KVP("Pipe"));
    this.TheItems.Add(GetRows_KVP("Line"));
  }
}
```

Comment: The ItemsControl was an improvement over ListView, which ruined the dynamic `DataGrid ColumnWidth="*"`, but I will surely try ListBox`, as well as your other points. Thanks Again!

Comment: But, I still see the 3 dots and the error msg as in the screenshot in my Q, although I changed the method to a property, did a clean and rebuild, and the binding works, and all data is shown in the UI. (I removed the assignment to ItemsSource in code-behind)

Comment: Of course, the assignment to ItemsSource must be removed. Like in my example. *"But, I still see the 3 dots and the error msg as in the screenshot in my Q, although I changed the method to a property"* - this is not possible if you follow the example. You can't/shouldn't bind to the DataContext from inside a UserControl. As stated in my answer you must use ElementName or RelativeSource. Let me know if you are still not able to fix the error .

Comment: The error msg is fixed, VS showed a suggested fix, which added namespaces to the XAML. The only thing that is strange that this "fix" did not make a difference in what was shown on the UI, it just fixed the error message. For the record, the black magic added was: `xmlns:models="clr-namespace:xaml_test.Palettes.Models"` and `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:ObjectProperty}"`

Comment: When I move the property for binding to ItemsSource to a class in the Models namespace, the binding fails, no data shown on UI, but NO ERROR msg with the 3 small dots in the XAML. Anyway, I have working code to play with and will go on to test my tabbing problem :-)

Comment: But the message you see is not an error message. It's just the designer telling you that it can't resolve the data context at design time. If this had been an error there would be squiggles. That's why `DesignInstance ` "solves" it because it tells the designer what the data context is at design time.

Comment: *"When I move the property for binding to ItemsSource to a class in the Models namespace, the binding fails"* - Are you talking about the `TheItems` property?

Comment: I will look at your last suggestion and your code, great learning material, at my next working day, either friday, or mid next week. It is now quite late at my timezone. Thanks so far!!!

Comment: Have a nice evening.